# Suitable method to estimate confidence intervals for an extreme order statistic

Tags: confidence-interval, nonparametric, resampling

I have a sampling distribution generated by computing the maximum across many samples. I'd now like to generate an estimate for what the true maximum parameter is within the population I sampled from. How can I do this? I thought about the bootstrap, but it didn't work well in estimating the maximum. Can anyone suggest a method to estimate the maximum from my sampling distribution?

Comment: What can you tell us about your population? Is it bounded?

Comment: No, it is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in looking into the [Generalized extreme value distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution), which can be viewed as the limiting distribution of maxima of sets of iid random variables.

For practical use, the `R` package [evd](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/evd/) has a function which will fit the GEV (`fitgev` appropriately enough) and the `R` package [evir](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/evir/) has one as well (`gev`).